# Android application will not go fullscreen

Tags: android

This is my android manifest.xml which links to theme.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brokenphysics.issb">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ISSB">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.ISSB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

what ever I do I can't get the app to go fullscreen and hide the status and navigation bars.

Answer (score 0):

currently you are removing only ActionBar/Toolbar/title, which belongs to your `Activity` (which fits by default between status bar and navigation bar, both visible). And you are looking for Immersive mode, check out official [DOC](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) how to enable (hint: you need also Java/Kotlin code, you won't style it with XML only)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hide Statusbar     
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

this code will hide status bar